# Ruby string escape for supplementary plane Unicode characters

Tags: ruby, string, unicode, unicode-escapes, supplementary

I know that I can escape a basic Unicode character in Ruby with the `\uNNNN` escape sequence. For example, for a smiling face [U+263A](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2603/index.htm) (☺) I can use the string literal `"\u2603"`.

How do I escape Unicode characters greater than U+FFFF that fall outside the [basic multilingual plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)), like a winking face: [U+1F609](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f609/index.htm) (😉)?

Using the surrogate pair form like in Java doesn't work; it results in an invalid string that contains the individual surrogate code points:

```
s = "\uD83D\uDE09" # => "\xED\xA0\xBD\xED\xB8\x89"
s.valid_encoding? # => false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the escape sequence **`\u{XXXXXX}`**, where `XXXXXX` is between 1 and 6 hex digits:

```
s = "\u{1F609}" # => ""
```

The braces can also contain multiple runs separated by single spaces or tabs to encode multiple characters:

```
s = "\u{41f 440 438 432 435 442 2c 20 43c 438 440}!" # => "Привет, мир!"
```

You could also use byte escapes to write a literal that contains the UTF-8 encoding of the character, though that's not very convenient, and doesn't *necessarily* result in a UTF-8-encoded string, if the file encoding differs:

```
# encoding: utf-8
s = "\xF0\x9F\x98\x89" # => ""
s.length # => 1
```

---

```
# encoding: iso-8859-1
s = "\xF0\x9F\x98\x89" # => "\xF0\x9F\x98\x89"
s.length # => 4
```